# Coding Python to handle JSON array inconsistencies

Tags: python, arrays, json, api, jagged-arrays

I've been playing with Python grabbing and parsing data from JSON API's. Specifically, I am working with the CTA (Chicago Transit Authority) Train Tracker API.

I periodically receive a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` that I tracked down to a when an array of multiple 'train' runs exists versus a single 'train' run. The single run is not in an array of runs.

```
{'ctatt':
 {'tmst': '2018-03-05T01:59:10',
 'errCd': '0',
 'errNm': None,
 'route': [{'@name': 'g'},
           {'@name': 'y',
            'train': {'rn': '030',
                     .....
                      'heading': '302'},
           {'@name': 'blue',
            'train': [{'rn': '125',
                     .....
                       'heading': '302'},
                      {'rn': '127',
                     ..... 
                       'heading': '278'},
```

The 'g' route has no instances of runs.
The 'y' route has 1 run.

```
  'train': {'rn':}
```

the 'blue' route has multiple runs.

```
  'train': [{'rn': ...},{'rn': ...},{'rn': ...}]
```

The code I'm using to parse through handles the lack of runs and multiple runs. It hits the `TypeError` with 1 run.

```
for train_rt in trains_data['ctatt']['route']:
    line_name = train_rt['@name']
    if train_rt.get('train', 'None') != 'None':
        for train_run in train_rt['train']:
```

What is the best way to handle just a single run that's not in the array?

[2 Yellow Line Runs in Chrome: Dev Tools: Network: Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTBoj.png)

[1 Yellow Line Run in Chrome: Dev Tools: Network: Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAteG.png)

An inconsistency I noticed is, if I query a single route, the routes still are in an array of 1 route.

Comment: Couldn't you check the `type` of the value to the `'train'` key and then handle as needed?

Comment: Side note: Just use `if 'train' in train_rt:`. Using a `'None'` string there has no advantages, and a big downside that it looks confusing as to why you are using such a special string value as a sentinel.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, the default return would be `'None'` but I had added that code trying to figure out error. I originally had `if train_rt.get('train') != None:` but I'm sure there is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- explicitly test for a list or dictionary, with `isinstance()`
- put your access in a `try:...except` and catch the `TypeError`, then proceed to treat it as a single element.

It won't matter all that much which one you pick (but there [can be a performance difference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663)), pick the style you feel works best for your code.

For example, if you used an `isistance()` test, you could *add* a list around the single element so the rest of your code doesn't have to change:

```
for train_rt in trains_data['ctatt']['route']:
    line_name = train_rt['@name']

    train_runs = train_rt.get('train', [])
    if not isinstance(train_runs, list):
        # single entry, wrap
        train_runs = [train_runs]

    for train_run in train_runs:
        # ...
```

Note that if the `'train'` key is missing, the above code again normalises by using an empty list. That allows you to avoid another `if` test, because now the `for` loop will not iterate at all.

If you have a support contact for that API, I'd at least report the issue and point out that their data structure is inconsistent.

Comment: I've seen the `'try: ...except'` in a lot of code and need to read up on it. Catching the errors and making my code more robust is my next step before I move on to anything else.

Comment: Thanks, BTW! I learned a few things I really like from that code! I will contact them now I know someone else also thinks it is inconsistent.

Comment: @Neal Yes, you definitely need to learn `try`/`except`. In Python, most things use duck typing (something is an X if it can perform X's operations), and exceptions are used pervasively in comparison to most languages. So it's usually Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission—`try` something, and then write the code that handles `except` cases. In this case, I think Martijn's "Look Before You Leap" solution with `isinstance` is probably cleaner (as he says, either one will work, but his instincts made him write it this way first…), but EAFP is very often the right answer.